# Delete Image from game in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**1. Summarize the problem**

> The following second code should delete the line that gets cloned in the first script.
> The command `Destroy()` doesn't delete it.

**2. Describe what you've tried**

> I've tried searching around for similar cases but i can't find what i need.
> No Error message appear

**3. Show some code**

> Code that creates the Image

```
Image CloneLine = Instantiate(Line);
```

> Code that should but doesn't delete the Image

```
Destroy(Linee[i]); //The name is different from the CloneLine cause it gets deleted from another script.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Destroy(Linee[i]);` command is missing one part.
By writing it like that it would only delete the image.
To delete the gameobject it should be written: `Destroy(Linee[i].gameobject);`

I found out about this later